# Clear text input on click with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

How can I clear a text input on click of a button using angularJS?

[image: Search input]

The X is a seperate link, on which I would like to trigger a function.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchAll">
<a class="clear" data-ng-click="clearSearch()">X</a>
```

Comment: Add your HTML of the input please.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just clear the scope model value on click event and it should do the trick for you.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchAll" />
<a class="clear" ng-click="searchAll = null">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

Or if you keep your controller's `$scope` function and clear it from there. Make sure you've set your controller correctly.

```
$scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.searchAll = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but only if the code is inline and not in a seperate JS file. Could you tell me how you could make it work in a seperate JS file?

Comment: See my edit. But why would you want to add additional code that doesn't require it?

Comment: earlier I were using *$scope.searchAll = "";* Well it were also working,,,there were some other scenario happening...overall thanks for suggesting *null* will also work.

Answer (score 15):

```
$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    $scope.searchAll = "";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzPJD/

JsFiddle of how you could do it without using inline JS.

Answer (score 14):

An easier and shorter way is:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchAll">
 <a class="clear" data-ng-click="searchAll = '' ">X</a>
```

This has always worked for me.

Comment: when we click on "X" then the model value of "searchAll" will become empty because we have assigned  empty string to that model when we click on "X" . !!data-ng-click="searchAll = ' '    "!!. Good about this is we don't have to make and call a separate function for just one line of code.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to clean up the whole form, you can use such approach.
This is your model into controller:

```
    $scope.registrationForm = {
    'firstName'     : '',
    'lastName'      : ''
};
```

Your HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="registrForm" role="form">
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       name="firstName"
                       id="firstName"
                       ng-model="registrationForm.firstName"
                       placeholder="First name"
                       required> First name
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       name="lastName"
                       id="lastName"
                       ng-model="registrationForm.lastName"
                       placeholder="Last name"
                       required> Last name
</form>
```

Then, you should clone/save your clear state by:

```
$scope.originForm = angular.copy($scope.registrationForm);
```

Your reset function will be:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(){
    $scope.registrationForm = angular.copy($scope.originForm); // Assign clear state to modified form 
    $scope.registrForm.$setPristine(); // this line will update status of your form, but will not clean your data, where `registrForm` - name of form.
};
```

In such way you are able to clean up the whole your form

Comment: I do implement your solution and work´s for me, i do reveive a warning : TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.resetForm can i fix this warning ?

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to clear/reset the text field on click is to clear/reset the scope

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchAll" ng-click="clearfunction(this)"/>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.clearfunction=function(event){
   event.searchAll=null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from [Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708786/2790364) answer, but when we use,

`ng-click="searchAll = null"` in the filter, it makes the model values as `null` and in-turn the search doesn't work with its normal functionality, so it would be better enough to use `ng-click="searchAll = ''"`  instead

Comment: Can you speak of the XSS implications when using this method?

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Controller**

```
$scope.clearSearch = function() {
     $scope.searchAll = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 this.searchAll = element(by.xpath('path here'));
 this.searchAll.sendKeys('');
```