# how to know scope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created template as below

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-light bar-subheader bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="select city...">
        <button ng-if="search.length" class="customIcon button button-icon ion-close-circled input-button"></button>
      </label>
      <button class="button button-clear">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
```

my issue is when I put below code in button inside label it will not work but if I put same code in button outside label it works

```
ng-click="search=''"
```

Comment: plz explain what you are trying to do..

Comment: I am trying to clear / reset my textbox

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21708786/3164682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for help. 
But I found solution, it turnout that button ng-click will not work inside the label, so I change label to div which start working every thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ngIf` directive creates a new child scope, so `search=''` becomes local child scope property `search` which has nothing to do with parent scope `search` model you are after.

The simplest fix is to use `ngShow` instead which only hides button but deal with the same scope:

```
<button ng-show="search.length" ng-click="search=''" class="customIcon button button-icon ion-close-circled input-button"></button>
```

You could also overcome it with parent scope reference: `ng-if="search.length" ng-click="$parent.search=''"`, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Then you should probably build a demo, because this is the thing I described.

Comment: Hi, It is working in plnkr and it is acting different. Is it possible that I can send you files and you can check please