# Can't clear input field in Angular on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am stuck and I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. So this is the HTML I am using:

```
<ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
  <label>
    <input class="searchField" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="findAndSearch" />
    <a class="clear" ng-click="findAndSearch = '' ">X</a>
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
  </label>
</ion-searchbar>
```

And this is the output HTML *when I have typed / typing* something into my input field:

```
<ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
  <label>
    <input class="searchField ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="findAndSearch" />
    <a class="clear" ng-click="findAndSearch = '' ">X</a>
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
  </label>
</ion-searchbar>
```

So what does this say? It says that it automatically puts the classname `ng-not-empty` and `ng-not-empty` when it's respectively being not empty and being empty (not filled in).

Whenever I click on the button I've made, it doesn't do a thing. I have no errors in my console, but as I said: whenever I write something into my input field, I can't reset it / remove it with this button.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or what might be going wrong?

PS: I already tried every possible solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708689/clear-text-input-on-click-with-angularjs).

Comment: Have you tried to create a method in your controller to clean the findAndSearch variable ?

Comment: Yes, I did... whatever I do, I can't get rid of the ''ng-not-empty" classname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have fixed this problem and I still don't know why or what is causing it, but the fix is like this:

```
    <ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
      <label>
        <input class="searchField" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="findAndSearch" />
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      </label>
      <a class="clear" ng-click="findAndSearch = '' ">X</a>

    </ion-searchbar>
```

As you can see, I have put the *anchor* with the `ng-click` outside of the `label` element and now, suddenly, it works. Unbelievable.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I've got something from Angular Documentation.

It's realted to a button, but I don't think this is a problem.

Check this out: [Clear Model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

> The next example shows how to debounce model changes. Model will be
>   updated only 1 sec after last change. If the Clear button is pressed,
>   any debounced action is canceled and the value becomes empty.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="userName"
           ng-model="user.name"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button><br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
</div>
```

Not the debounce, but the $rollbackViewValue() to specific field in your form.
And after user.name=''

Please, try and tell us.

In your code:

```
<a class="clear" ng-click="findAndSearch = '' ">X</a>
```

You try:

```
<a class="clear" ng-click="yourForm.(give some ID to your input).$rollbackViewValue(); findAndSearch = ''">X</a>
```

Comment: Can you give an example with my snippet? I don't get what you exactly mean, because I see a lot of things I don't have and I don't need...

Comment: Thanks Elek, yet this isn't working either. Nothing happens.

Comment: I am upvoting you though, you deserve that. I have fixed the problem, which was a very very odd fix, and I'll show you in the answer I'l give.

Comment: @Siyah I think you might post that answer using the Answer Your Question button, at the bottom of the page, I guess you'll have more points and a Self Learner badge because of it ..

Comment: Thanks Elek, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have created snippet on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z4zuc0r/3/) with your code and all work fine:
ngModel is cleared and class ng-not-empty removed when you click on X. So looks like the problem not in this piece of code

```
   <div ng-app="app">
<ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
  <label>
    <input class="searchField" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="findAndSearch" />
    <a class="clear" ng-click="findAndSearch = '' ">X</a>
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
  </label>
</ion-searchbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks... I have the same issue indeed. It works everywhere, except on my app. It drives me crazy.

Comment: @Siyah I could only suggest remove code around at try understand what lead to error

Comment: Thanks for the help Maksimr, I appreciate it.